# Dereferencing a null pointer

Tags: c, nullpointerexception

Why I can't dereference a null pointer? That is, why I can't read/write memory which address is simply 0?

Does the base pointer of my process have a different address? If yes, is there a way to obtain the lower memory adders available for the default heap of my process?

Comment: The Operating System is protecting you from yourself.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you wish to do this?

Comment: @SergeyL. No, there is no a particular reason, just curiosity.

Comment: Actually, in primitive implementations of C you *could* dereference a null pointer (assuming NULL is defined as zero) and access the zeroth byte in the computer RAM.  But on modern systems that location is "storage protected" and will result in a error if you attempt to access.

Comment: (It's generally a bad idea to allow programs to reference areas of storage they have reason to access.  All too often some idiot programmer builds in a dependency on such a reference and when the OS implementation changes the program breaks.  The OS programmers of course get blamed for "incompatibility".)

Comment: Not just primitive implementations, but many embedded processors use 0 for NULL but have valid memory at address 0. For example, on some embedded ARM processors, address 0 is the first location in the interrupt table and in flash memory. Fortunately, trying to write through a NULL pointer will still trap unless you are programming flash.

Comment: (Oops -- make that ".. they have NO reason to access.")

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A null pointer is not a pointer to "memory [whose] address is simply 0". It's just a special pointer that doesn't point to anything valid.

The C language says that there are no requirements on the behaviour of a program that dereferences a null pointer.

Comment: @OP: do note that a null pointer is not necessarily 0 bitwise.

Answer (score 3):

The VM page that sits at address `(void *)0x0` or `NULL` is by default not mapped in any modern OS, thus dereferencing a `NULL` pointer will result in a segmentation violation.

`NULL` pointers are frequently used as pointers that point nowhere.

Yes, you can obtain the address of your text, stack and heap bases. For stack this is relatively easy, for text and heap you will need to consult `/proc/self/smaps` (if you have `procfs`).

Comment: that's assuming linux

Answer (score 3):

Why can't I make a phone call to `00000 000 000`? I should be able to do this.

Comment: Care to explain what you intend to say here? Is `00000 000 000` not a valid phone number for you? Is it? What does it relate to here?

Comment: @sehe "proof" by analogy. There's no reason that a phone services operator should be required to connect a call to some magical non-existent "sentinel" number `00000 000 000`, just as there's no reason for dereferencing a NULL pointer to make any sense. There's nothing at the other end.

Comment: Okay. Got it. <padding/>

Comment: @sehe: What, no Unicode bananas? I thought we were friends... :(

Comment: I can't afford any browsers that show them anyways. I'm being inclusionist here. You can be my friend, you can be my friend too, no need to support Unicode bananas, you can be friend (_"It's okay, just pad it in your own words, brother"_)

Answer (score 2):

A pointer having a value of NULL should be thought of as something that "points to *nothing*", instead of something that points to some memory address corresponding to 0.

Comment: I prefer to think of it as a pointer that does not point (*a pointer on vacations*).

Answer (score 2):

[C 2011 online draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)

> **6.3.2.3 Pointers**
> ...
> 3 An integer constant expression with the value 0, or such an expression cast to type
> `void *`, is called a *null pointer constant.*
> <sup>66)</sup> If a null pointer constant is converted to a
> pointer type, the resulting pointer, called a *null pointer*, **is guaranteed to compare unequal
> to a pointer to any object or function**.
>
> ---
>
> <sup>66) The macro `NULL` is deﬁned in `<stddef.h>` (and other headers) as a null pointer constant; see 7.19.</sup>

Emphasis mine.  `NULL` is defined to be an *invalid* pointer value that represents a well-defined "nowhere".  You can't dereference it because there's nothing to dereference.  Note that although the null pointer *constant* is always 0-valued, the null pointer *value* doesn't have to be; it can be `0x00000000` or `0xDEADBEEF` or something completely different; that's up to the platform.

TL;DR, `NULL` doesn't represent address `0`; it represents "no address".